# Can I use a remote build file in Ant?

Tags: svn, ant, build, build-process

I have an ant script created by a previous employee of our company and it contains tasks to check projects out of Subversion.  The only problem I have though is that the build file is actually part of a project in subversion.  So in order to use the script I first have to checkout that project so that I have a copy of the build.xml file locally.

Is it possible at all to point ant to a remote file in a subversion repository? e.g.:

```
ant -f svn+ssh://path/to/build.xml
```

I tried it like this and it doesn't like it, but I was wondering if there was another way of doing it?

Comment: lol, it was indeed Adam who wrote this monstrosity :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the source](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/ant/core/trunk/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/Main.java?revision=1035336&view=markup#l486), this is not possible because the `-f` parameter is used to construct a plain old `java.io.File` — no fancy network access or SVN integration.

Can you not keep a checkout of that repo locally, or copy of that custom Ant Task in your classpath, as presumably its unlikely to change often?

Comment: I was just looking for a neat way of not having to have a local copy of it, but I guess I'll just have to make do.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `<Import>` task to import a local or remote build file in your `build.xml`.

See this question : [How can I best share Ant targets between projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829051/how-can-i-best-share-ant-targets-between-projects)